# Is there a policy for hacking-related or else unethical questions?

Tags: discussion, ethics

I've come to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18246837/python-urllib2-authentication-will-not-return-whether-it-was-successful-or-not) question on SO, where the asker's program purpose is obviously to crack some password on social networks.

- Should this kind of question be flagged for moderator attention ?
- Should I refrain from answering ?
- Should I consider this question as ... normal.

Comment: Sorry for the duplicate... I searched for keywords on this topic but _nefarious_ wasn't part of my vocabulary. I might suggest editing the title of that reference question ...

Comment: @WesleyMurch, looking for duplicates in Meta is much more easier than on SO though (mostly due to the breadth of subjects).

Comment: @OldCheckmark [I wouldn't have been able to find this](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=how+to+deal+with+hacking+questions). [My search queries would not go well.](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=what+do+i+do+about+questions+about+hacking) It is hard to find stuff if you don't already know what to look for.

Comment: @d-stroyer, sometimes duplicate questions are used to direct users to the reference question, so yeah it's all good.

Comment: Closed it, custom reason given in comments on the question.